# array manipulation from MATLAB to Python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

from MATLAB code:

```
a = rand(1,120);
    d=zeros(1,124);
    state=[1:120];
    fibre = [1  5   9   13  17  2   6   10  14  18  3   7   11  15  19  4   8   12  16  20  21  69  65  61  57  22  68  64  60  56  71  67  63  59  55  70  66  62  58  54  53  49  45  41  37  52  48  44  40  36  51  47  43  39  35  50  46  42  38  34  121 117 113 109 105 120 116 112 108 104 119 115 111 107 103 118 114 110 106 102 101 97  93  89  85  100 96  92  88  84  99  95  91  87  83  98  94  90  86  82  81  79  77  75  33  80  27  29  31  122 25  78  76  74  123 26  28  30  32  124];
    d(fibre)=a(state);
```

to Python code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(120,219,1)
d=np.zeros([124])
state = np.arange(0,120,1)
fibre = np.array([1,5,9,13,17,2,6,10,14,18,3,7,11,15,19,4,8,12,16,20,21,69,65,61,57,22,68,64,60,56,71,67,63,59,55,70,66,62,58,54,53,49,45,41,37,52,48,44,40,36,51,47,43,39,35,50,46,42,38,34,121,117,113,109,105,120,116,112,108,104,119,115,111,107,103,118,114,110,106,102,101,97,93,89,85,100,96,92,88,84,99,95,91,87,83,98,94,90,86,82,81,79,77,75,33,80,27,29,31,122,25,78,76,74,123,26,28,30,32,124,72,73,23,24])
d[fibre]=a[state]
```

The python code throw an exception in regards to array size, any recommendations on how to fix this?

Comment: Python indexing starts at `0` so `d[124]` does not exist.

Comment: something is wrong with your code. numpy as no randm method

Comment: What is the `shape` of `a`.  As in Matlab, use lots of diagnostic prints.

Comment: shape of a is (1,120) I edited with the correct random function!

Comment: `a[0,state]` and `d = np.zeros(125)` works. Check the shape of your arrays. python does [a,b-1] because it starts at 0

Comment: `    d[fibre]=a[0,state]
IndexError: too many indices for array`

Comment: Python code can be run now

Comment: 2  important differences: MATLAB indexing starts at 1, not 0, and MATLAB matrices are always 2d or large, numpy may be 1 or even 0d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your python script has two problem regarding to Matlab code:
In the second line you should generate random numbers such as:

```
a = np.random.rand(120)
```

and in the last line, like in comments said, you should know indexing in Matlab starts with 1 and python starts with 0, so your last line will be:

```
d[fibre-1]=a[state]
```

Comment: I am trying like this: `d=np.zeros([124])
state = np.arange(0,120,1)
JV_fibre = np.array([1,5,9,13,17,2,6,10,14,18,3,7,11,15,19,4,8,12,16,20,21,69,65,61,57,22,68,64,60,56,71,67,63,59,55,70,66,62,58,54,53,49,45,41,37,52,48,44,40,36,51,47,43,39,35,50,46,42,38,34,121,117,113,109,105,120,116,112,108,104,119,115,111,107,103,118,114,110,106,102,101,97,93,89,85,100,96,92,88,84,99,95,91,87,83,98,94,90,86,82,81,79,77,75,33,80,27,29,31,122,25,78,76,74,123,26,28,30,32,124])
JV_fibre = JV_fibre -1 d[JV_fibre] = a[state]` and is not working.

Comment: Mine works just fine!!
How do you generate a ?

Comment: you are correct. I had a problem in another part of the program/